# Plotting points in D3.js

Tags: javascript, json, api, d3.js, data-visualization

I've accessed an API and stored the data in two arrays. Now I'm trying to plot the data from the arrays on a graph in D3.js.

```
//Read the data
d3.json(BASE_URL).get(function(data) {
  console.log(data)

var data = data["near_earth_objects"]
console.log(data)
var today = [];
var neo = [];
var diameter = [];
var distance = [];
for (today of data["2020-01-09"]) {
console.log(today)

diameter.push(Math.round(today["estimated_diameter"]["feet"]["estimated_diameter_max"]))

for (approach of today["close_approach_data"]){
console.log(approach)
distance.push(Math.round(approach["miss_distance"]["lunar"]))
}
}

console.log(diameter)
console.log(distance)
```

What will be X and Y are the arrays "diameter" and "distance."

```
    .selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.distance); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.diamter); } )
      .attr("r", 1.5)
      .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
```

I tried plugging in the variables at cx and cy but it didn't work! I was able to plot the points if I read from a csv file but I am now reading from json.

Very new at programming so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what my console.logs are putting out. The two arrays are at the bottom.
[image: Data samples]

Comment: can you add some data sample or the BASE_URL you are to plot? that would help solving this issue.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I attached a screenshot to my main post.

Comment: This is still not clear, can you add a fiddle for this with minimal reproducible sample of what you are trying to achieve.  https://jsfiddle.net/ or at least post you data object here a single object can be enough.

Comment: [Here is a link to my project](https://jsfiddle.net/jk5moa9c/) Never used fiddle before but I think the link should work.

Comment: Is the typo `y(d.diamter);` also in your real code?

Comment: Nope just a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes:
When you draw circles you asume that `data` object is an array with elements which contains "diameter" and "distance" properties:

```
svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.distance); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.diamter); } )
```

but in fact you use your initial `data` object which have complex structure.

So, you should add something like this:

```
data2 = diameter.map(function(e,i){return {'diameter': e, 'distance':distance[i]}})
```

and change your circle rendering to data2:

```
 svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot")
    .data(data2)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.distance); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.diameter); } )
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
```

And second mistake is "diamter" instead of "diameter" in `.attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.diamter); }`